# Create JKS file from Base64 encoded string

Tags: ssl, truststore

I have a Base64 encoded String that I need to transform into a JKS file. The string is simply the encoded contents of the JKS file I need to recreate on my machine. Is this something that's possible? Searching high and low, I have found no information on how to do this, any links or documentation would be very helpful

Answer (score 7):

In UNIX you can decode a base64 encoded string to a file using:

`cat file_containing_base64 | base64 --decode > output.jks`

or

`echo base64_string | base64 --decode > output.jks`